# How to spot UDP timeout on gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

When there are 3 connections to the camera already, it does not connect anymore and the below message can be seen in the log.

```
 0:00:07.261098475     1 0x5643d36846a0 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5964:gst_rtspsrc_reconnect:<rtspsrc0> warning: Could not receive any UDP packets for 5.0000 seconds, maybe your firewall is blocking it. Retrying using a tcp connection.
```

Need to handle the timeout programmatically.
The pipeline bus is being watched, but no messages come there at the time of the issue:

```
   auto pipeline =
        gst_utils::wrapPtr(gst_parse_launch(pipelineStr.c_str(), &err));
...

    auto bus = gst_utils::wrapPtr(gst_element_get_bus(pipeline.get()));
    gst_bus_add_watch(bus.get(), busWatch, this);
```

Also when requesting pipeline state, it is PLAYING, as per requested change, so cannot use it to spot the timeout.

**Is it possible to handle the timeout by catching this event or in some other way ?**

Below is the code referenced in the log message:

> GST_ELEMENT_WARNING (src, RESOURCE, READ, (NULL),
>       ("Could not receive any UDP packets for %.4f seconds, maybe your "
>           "firewall is blocking it. Retrying using a tcp connection.",
>           gst_guint64_to_gdouble (src->udp_timeout) / 1000000.0));